# How to package and distribute my JavaFX Application in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, exe

I just wrote a JavaFX app in IntelliJ using Java 11.0.3 and JavaFX 11.0.2. Now I need to package the project for distribution and I can’t find a simple way to do so. Building as a JavaFX Application doesn't work because Java no longer includes Java FX Packager. Just building the .Jar file will not work because it doesn't include JavaFX. Is there a simple way for me to make a simple .jar or .exe file?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html. You can also use Maven or Gradle to build the app package.

Comment: The above comment might help you to build your application. If you need your application in .exe format you can use Launch4j to convert your jar to exe

Comment: No. There isn't.